# caffe cmake error by ccache

Tags: gcc, cmake, deep-learning, caffe

When I successfully 'cmake ..' caffe build, I preceed with 'make all' command but came up with an error below. I don't know if there is something wrong with NVCC or gcc.

```
[  1%] Built target proto
[  1%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/cuda_compile_generated_split_layer.cu.o
/usr/bin/ccache: invalid option -- 'E'
Usage:
ccache [options]
ccache compiler [compiler options]
compiler [compiler options]          (via symbolic link)

Options:
-c, --cleanup         delete old files and recalculate size counters
                      (normally not needed as this is done automatically)
-C, --clear           clear the cache completely
-F, --max-files=N     set maximum number of files in cache to N (use 0 for
                      no limit)
-M, --max-size=SIZE   set maximum size of cache to SIZE (use 0 for no
                      limit; available suffixes: G, M and K; default
                      suffix: G)
-s, --show-stats      show statistics summary
-z, --zero-stats      zero statistics counters

-h, --help            print this help text
-V, --version         print version and copyright information

See also <http://ccache.samba.org>.
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_split_layer.cu.o.cmake:206 (message):
Error generating
/home/gpuusr/lpq/caffe-332/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_split_layer.cu.o


make[2]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/cuda_compile_generated_split_layer.cu.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: As it states, there's no -E option for ccmake, it would be interesting if you post the according CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue trying to build OpenCV with CUDA support. There's some odd interaction between CMake, CUDA, and ccache that I don't understand, it's trying to call ccache with invalid arguments. You can bypass this by specifying your system compiler for CUDA instead:

`cmake -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ ..`

(Or whatever compiler you're using.)

Comment: Adding to this answer: if you want to use ccache for the cuda step, use this line instead: `cmake -DCUDA_HOST_COMPILER=/usr/lib/ccache/g++`

Answer (score 1):

This used to be a bug in CMake. It was fixed with CMake release 3.4.0.

## Proof

The code from [here](http://computer-graphics.se/hello-world-for-cuda.html) can be compiled with the following `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.9 FATAL_ERROR)
project(CudaTest)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
cuda_add_executable(hello_cuda hello.cu)
```

- With `/usr/lib/ccache` on the `PATH`.
- Building once with **CMake 3.2** and once with **CMake 3.7.1**.
- CMake 3.2:

  ```
  $ make
  ...
  /path/to/build-3.2
  [100%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/hello_cuda.dir/hello_cuda_generated_hello.cu.o
  /usr/bin/ccache: invalid option -- 'E'
  ...
  ```
- CMake 3.7.1:

  ```
  $ make
  [ 50%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/hello_cuda.dir/hello_cuda_generated_hello.cu.o
  [100%] Linking CXX executable hello_cuda
  [100%] Built target hello_cuda
  ```

### For the record

A small git bisect run over CMake 3.2.2 -- 3.7.1 shows that this is the commit that fixed it:

```
commit b405f01daaeaeda98d448e2f0d71ea685757a5bd
Author: Bill Hoffman <bill.hoffman@kitware.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 12 14:16:09 2015 -0400

    FindCUDA: Resolve a host compiler symlink only if it is Apple cc - clang

    Otherwise using a "cc -> ccache" or similar symlink as the compiler
    causes FindCUDA to select ccache as the host compiler.  Update the logic
    added by commit v3.1.0-rc1~354^2 (FindCUDA: Fix OSX Clang & no C
    language enabled, 2014-06-12) to apply only in the specific case it is
    needed.
```

This commit went into CMake 3.4.0. Compare `git rev-list v3.4.0 | grep b405f01` with `git rev-list v3.3.2 | grep b405f01`.

Comment: I am seeing this bug in cmake 3.6.2. Perhaps there was a regression for that version?